# how to let ss << f work like printf("%g", f);

Tags: c++, printf

In my C++ program, the initial code is

```
stringstream ss;
vector<float>::iterator v;
ss << std::left << std::setw(12) << std::setiosflags(std::ios::fixed)
                << std::setprecision(6) << *v;
```

But for some `v`, for example, `2345999998888.44445332222`, the output will be very long. So I want that

```
ss << *v
```

has the same effect like

```
printf("%g", f);
```

and later, I just used `ss << *v`. Amazingly, the output is the same like `%g` does.

Does `stringstream` automatically choose the better way to output a value? Or I just made a tricky mistake?

Comment: There are [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) on what `%g` does. Unfortunately, I don't think there's any built-in streams equivalent.

Comment: This cannot be done with sstream classes. ios classes can do something like " cout << setprecision(2) << std::scientific << 123.4; "

Comment: @Shooter, That works exactly the same way regardless of which `std::ostream` implementation is used.

Comment: @Shooter: `sstream` classes are derived from ios classes and thus support all of the same formatting options.

Comment: You can always `char buf[100]; snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%g", *v); ss << buf;`

Comment: punctuations must be put right after the first word and then followed by a space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%g` is [documented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) as follows:

> converts floating-point number to decimal or decimal exponent notation depending on the value and the precision.
>
> For the **g** conversion style conversion with style **e** or **f** will be performed.
>
> For the **G** conversion style conversion with style **E** or **F** will be performed.
>
> Let *P* equal the precision if nonzero, `6` if the precision is not specified, or `1` if the precision is ​`0`​. Then, if a conversion with style **E** would have an exponent of X:
>
> - if *P > X ≥ −4*, the conversion is with style **f** or **F** and precision *P − 1 − X*.
> - otherwise, the conversion is with style **e** or **E** and precision *P − 1*.
>
> Unless *alternative representation* is requested the trailing zeros are removed, also the decimal point character is removed if no fractional part is left. For infinity and not-a-number conversion style see notes.

The stream equivalent would look something like this:

```
#include <cmath>

float f = ...;
int X; // the exponent
int P = 6; // the desired precision

X = std::floor(std::log10(f));

std::stringstream ss;
if ((P > X) && (X >= −4))
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(P - 1 − X);
else
    ss << std::scientific << std::setprecision(P - 1); 
ss << f;
```